# Different ways of using ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries

Tags: c#, xaml

I was going through some code in our product and saw some colleagues using ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries in a way I had not seen it used before:

```xml
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <toolTips:ToolTips />
                <styles:ControlStyles />
                <icons:IconDictionary />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

`tooltips:ToolTips` and all the other elements in the MergedDictionaries are ResourceDictionaries.

The regular way of using these according to the internet is to use `<ResourceDictionary Source="uri to your xaml file"/>`.

So is there any practical difference between both?

If this way works why isn't it used more often as it plays well with code completion?

Answer (score 2):

I've used `ResourceDicionary` this way only once on a big project and it was benefical in my situation.

Suppose that you have `ResourceDictionary` in `MyDictionary.xaml` file.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                x:Class="YourNamespace.MyDictionary">    
</ResourceDictionary>
```

You can add an `x:Class` attribute to the `ResourceDictionary` element and specify the fully qualified name of the code-behind class.

Let's create `MyDictionary.xaml.cs` with class `MyDictionary` (name can be different from the name of the xaml file).

```
public partial class MyDictionary
{
    public MyDictionary()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

A class must be a partial class. The constructor must be added to the class and `InitializeComponent` method must be called. The `InitializeComponent` method will be automatically generated for the class if you set the `x:Class` attribute in `MyDictionary.xaml`

Now you can reference `MyDictionary` in `MergedDictionaries`

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <local:MyDictionary/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

If you add some `DataTemplate` into `MyDictionary.xaml` you can create event handlers in code-behind (handlers will be automatically generated by VS)

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                x:Class="YourNamespace.MyDictionary">    
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
        <Button Click="Button_Click"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MyDictionary
{
    public MyDictionary()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // custom logic
        // edit another element, etc.
    }
}
```

If the class is inherited from the `ResourceDictionary` class then other resources can be accessed from the code-behind.

Example of usage of data template defined in `MyDictonary`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <local:MyDictionary/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}"/>
</Grid>
```

From my point of view the biggest advantages are that you can encapsulate logic into separated files (it's easy to maintain and add new features in big projects) and avoid referencing `ResourceDictionaries` by `<ResourceDictionary Source="uri to your xaml file"/>`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining how to be able to use a ResourceDictionary in that way. What is really interesting would be to know if there are any runtime penalties or other not so obvious behaviour differences for doing it one way or another.